# How to set grid view header name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have one Asp.net grid view in which values are coming from two SQL tables. say Table names are Table 1 & Table 2. Table 1 has one column name **Question**. I want if **Question** column has records/rows then this value should be the header of Gridview.
E.g. **Question** has row value as "What is your name" then "What is your name" will be the one column header in that grid view. 
Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this? 
Thanks

Comment: Surely you can achieve this by writing code. Did you try that? What issue you are facing in that?

Comment: Please include the code that you already produced regarding your question. Describe what you expect that code to do and what it does instead. If it produces an error, include the error message. To get good answers here it helps a lot to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and about [how to give good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting a question.

Comment: @anothernode ok Thanks for the advice

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Sir I am new to both in coding & in a stack overflow.If I knew the logic or code then why should I ask?

Comment: No website on internet can teach logic and there are plenty of them which can teach how to code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: https://online.stanford.edu/course/introduction-logic

Comment: @ibrahimshaikh No harm in taking it if that helps...

Comment: Thanks for this help.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
myGrivView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "My header text";
```

you can also use it inside a loop in which data  coming from the different source like sql sp